# A reliable way of creating a bootable usb in kubuntu?

Tags: boot, usb, system-installation, live-usb

Unetbootin installs grub which then boots the system you specify. I don't like that. Linux live ISOs are directly bootable and usually contain a pre-configured grub install of their own which among other things, tends to work better. The `dd` command is the second most commonly recommended method of creating a bootable usb from an ISO. Honestly i would love it except for two things. First, i cant seem to make it work. Second, i dont fully understand its use (which may be a decent explanation for the first reason)

I have found a utility called "rufus" which works like a charm, every time. It only runs on Windows, which i will never use again now that i have a workable understanding of linux.

So is there another, 100% reliable, way to create a bootable USB from an ISO?

if nothing comes to mind, maybe some insight on the `dd` command could help...

EDIT:

convoluted, excessively complex, and even c/c++ solutions are more than welcome (i wouldn't mind coding my own utility)

Comment: `dd` has good man page. It's not so complicated as `bash`. Spend 10 minutes and you are expert ;).

Comment: @Danatela so in making a usb from an iso would i want to use the unmounted device (/dev/sdb) or the mounted device (/mnt/mymountpoint) as the output file? furthermore, should i create an fs or does the iso contain the fs?

Comment: I tried other tools, but `dd` always seems to work. I use the Linux Mint sample from their community site. `sudo dd if=~/Desktop/linuxmint.iso of=/dev/sdx oflag=direct  bs=1048576` found at: http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/744

Comment: Of course, you should use device (`of=/dev/sdb`) because once it was mounted it will create unusable file on the mountpoint. And yes, ISO contains the filesystem. But remember that you will not be able to use persistence file when you use `dd` and probably you will not able to write anything else on that stick.

Comment: @Danatela a thought... wouldnt i be able to create an extra partition (using say, fdisk) in the unallocated space? to that end couldnt i just resize the partition created by dd?

Comment: AFAIK ISO has no partitions. BTW why don't you like UNetbootin?

Comment: @Danatela because it only works for booting linux ISOs. ISOs have more uses than that (such as CD backups). Also, it cant seem to configure grub properly for me and i always have to edit the commands... i was thinking of it more as BEING a partition in and of itself... not having one... Probably a huge misunderstanding though

Comment: Ah. Didn't think about other CD images. [Come into chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room).

Comment: Did you look at [Yumi](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/)?

Comment: @Mitch indeed i did... but didn't use it for the same reason you wouldn't use something called "free text editor" or "easy file converter"... I didn't know what to think... I find myself wary of anything which doesn't have an established reputation... there are many potential solutions for any problem, so i prefer to be referred to them, instead of randomly trying things that i don't understand... can you give me any insight? does it work? have you examined the source?